# Function attribute [[clang::minsize]] does not behave as expected

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

[[[clang::minsize]]](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html):

> This attribute suggests that optimization passes and code generator passes make choices  that keep the code size of this function as small as possible and perform optimizations  that may sacrifice runtime performance in order to minimize the size of the generated code.

With the following code:

```
[[gnu::noinline]] int bar()
{
    return rand();
}

[[gnu::noinline]] int laa()
{
    return 129345;
}

[[clang::minsize]] int foo()
{
    return bar() + laa();
}
```

When using the `minsize` attribute it doesn't appear to perform any optimization:

[clang example](https://godbolt.org/z/r11jKEz7d)

I'm expecting something vaguely similar to GCC's `[[gnu::optimize("s")]]` which works nicely!

[gcc example](https://godbolt.org/z/5xvrzPY4s)

When clang is configured with Os:

```
foo():
        push    rax
        call    bar()
        add     eax, 129345
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

However, with O0 + the attribute:

```
foo():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        call    bar()
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], eax        # 4-byte Spill
        call    laa()
        mov     ecx, eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 4]        # 4-byte Reload
        add     eax, ecx
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Comment: You can't really expect optimizations with `-O0`.

Comment: Perhaps, I don't think it clang docs state that? And for the similar GCC flag optimizations do occur in that scenario.

Comment: GCC is notorious for doing some optimizations despite `O0`. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html "-O0 Means “no optimization”"

Comment: Not nesssarily disagreeing (just confused), `gnu::always_inline` seems like an optimisation and it will occur in O0.
https://godbolt.org/z/5axzofrjn

Comment: You can't _expect_ optimizations with `O0`. Some will happen depending on how the compiler is architected whatever the settings. If you want optimizations use `Os` or `O2` or specific `-f` flags for the things you care about.

Comment: Well, dang! Thanks!